# vue3 update image src dynamically

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to update an image dynamically but it is not updated.

According to the [doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html) I have a template:

```
<template>
   <section class="relative">
     <div class="">
        <img ref="heroImg" class="" src='../images/hero-bg-01.jpg' width="1440" height="577" />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Now I would like to update the **src** of my img and I do:

```
import {  ref, onMounted } from "vue";
export default {
   name: 'HeroTestimonials',
   props:["source", "dataV"],
   setup(){
      const heroImg = ref(null);

      onMounted(() => {
          const imgUrl = new URL('../images/hero-bg-02.jpg', import.meta.url).href;
          heroImg.src = imgUrl;
          console.log(heroImg);
      })
      return {heroImg}
   },
}
```

Into the console I have the message:

> {
> "_rawValue": null,
> "_shallow": false,
> "__v_isRef": true,
> "_value": null,
> "src": "http://localhost:3001/src/images/hero-bg-02.jpg" }

No errors but the image is not updated yet.

What's wrong?

Thanks for any suggestion!

[EDIT] - I've added the line *return {heroImg}* which was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the src attribute dynamic, you must use a v-bind in front of the attribute, for exemple v-bind:src="yourVariableHere" or use the shorthand :src. (you can see more here : https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind)

In your exemple you should do something like that :

```js
<img class="" :src='imgUrl' width="1440" height="577" />
```

Then, in your script section :

```js
<script>
    import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
    
    export default {
      name: 'App',
    
      setup() {
        const imgUrl = ref('../images/hero-bg-01.jpg')
    
        onMounted(() => {
          imgUrl.value = '../images/hero-bg-02.jpg';
        })
    
        return {
          imgUrl
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

However I'm not sure about doing that in the onMounted hook because the image would get replaced instantly

Comment: Thanks ,I solved right now using a similar solution.